# Performance differences between Windows Server Enterprise and Datacenter?

Tags: windows, performance, datacenter

I'm a student and participating on a Business Intelligence project at a german university.
We have our own hardware (one server) and currently planning to set up our server.

We can choose between two operating systems:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter Edition

The Datacenter Edition offers more features, especially for scalability of the hardware.
In our case there is no budget difference, whether we choose the Enterprise or the Datacenter edition.

**So our only concern is**, if the Datacenter Edition requires **more performance or resources** on a server compared to the Enterprise Edition.

Does anyone has some experience, comparing these two Editions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noe. Zero. Possibly some more ram, bu very little. At the end, DataCenter does nothing more than Enterprise unless conigured to in hard or software. Unless you scale up to those levels in hardare it makes no difference. DataCenter is mostly for LARGE boxes with EHAVY virtualaization (not it comes with the right to install unlimited windows bvirtual instances - Enterprise limtis you to I think 4, which makes it unfeasible for a virtual server of non-trivial size).